# In Westeros, is Guest Right invalidated if you got in on false pretence?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

If you get into somebody's house/keep/castle based on false pretence (claiming to be someone else than you are), or by sneaking in and then mingling with a crowd of visitors; then you eat from the food on the hosts' table; then you are discovered - do you have Guest Right? Or is it invalidated? And if so, can you be killed or are you just thrown out?

I'm of course asking for an answer based at least to some extent in GRRM's own writing, not just what would make sense.

Motivation: Mance Raider claiming in ASoS that he might have been safe had he been discovered in Winterfell since he'd already secured Guest Right.

Comment: Well, most people call that trespassing, and not "having a guest".

Comment: @Radhil: Most people live in reality rather than in Westeros.

Comment: True, but much of Westeros is based on (old) reality.  I'm not enough of a Westeros or Mance expert to answer and source in full, thus my comment, but every system of honor that included guest rights that I've heard of, those rights cannot be claimed if you were not invited in as an individual or party, or gained access under false pretense.  In more magical settings (Dresden Files) verbal judo can be tried to get the host to say you're a guest, and hosts can be bound by that once admitted.  That's not Westeros though, by a longshot.

Comment: @Radhil: I would upvote an answer describing known historic Guest Rights in different societies and concluding what GRRM probably meant based on those.

Answer (score 1):

Eating of a Lords bread and salt means you are safe for the day at least nothing is said of the morrow

However to invoke guest rights the guest in question must have no ill meaning towards his host in Mance's case one could argue he was spying on Lord Stark and his guest rights were invalid because of this

Actually this would work for your example as well if someone entered under false pretenses even if they eat and drink they are not technically a guest even if all they actually wanted was a meal they broke the laws of hospitality first by stealing from the host (assuming you define getting something by dishonest means as stealing)

What would happen probably depends on the host and who you are Mance could have been executed by Lord Stark or Stark could have chosen to allow guest rights to stand and simply kicked him out (then sent his men to arrest him once you kick someone out they are no longer a guest) if a peasant did this to Lord Bolton there would be a skinless corpse somewhere in the dreadfort I imagine